# MongoDB and PHP Unable to retrieve data from db

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to use MongoDB and PHP for academic purposes (final year project) . However I am struggling to retrieve anything from the db.

I am using WAMP as local server, I have done the full configuration as presented on 10gen and PHP documentation. 
Ironically I can insert in the database but I cannot retrieve anything back.

insert.php code http://p.shrib.com/mongo?m=ro&v=nc

find.php code http://p.shrib.com/mongo_find?m=ro&v=nc

Please help me with ideas I am really struggling and I don't know what to try anymore.

Kind regards,
Adriana Costache

Comment: Are these the only 2 files involved? Can you `print_r($cursor)` before the `if` statement? Do you receive an error of any kind in the logs? Also small suggestion would be not to close the mongodb connection if you use latest versions of mongo.

Comment: Yes, these are the only 2 files involved print_r($cursor) doesn't bring back anything and the php file just causes an endless loop. I have also removed the close_connection statement. I have placed an echo after each statement and if something happens it happens once I add the $num_docs = $cursor->count(). I have tried findOne() and the behaviour is the same. I'm just trying to get something from the database, anything, but all I get is either a page loading endlessly or page not found error.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. What if you query via the mongo CLI directly instead of PHP? Does it return any results?

Comment: the query works just fine in the CLI. I have tried opening the connection using MonogClient instead of Mongo, the problem is the same!

Comment: What's your mongo php driver version?

Comment: php_mongo.dll VC6 for Apache - all others give errors

Comment: What exactly happens when you run that script? Is really nothing printed out at all? What happens in the mongod.log? What about the webserver error logs?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an array on the $collection->find() even when he is empty.

Example:

```
<?php

$query = array();

$cursor = $collection->find($query);

?>
```

Kind regards,
Ruben

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is check that the extension loads correctly in PHP.

I see you're using new Mongo(). This class is deprecated in favour of new MongoClient().

Upgrade your PHP/Apache and try installing the latest stable extension.

Let me know how it works.